# Is there a way to stop Google from indexing spam internal search results?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, links, spam, disallow

I've just seen in Google Search Console that Google is doing 3 things with spammy internal search links.
The link structure is always `www.example.com/search?q=[spammy link here]`

1. Around 500 are green and indexed (they don't appear on the sitemap but are indexed in the overall page indexing)
2. Around 300 are grey and blocked by `robots.txt` (the instruction here is disallow /search)
3. 400 more are orange, indexed, though blocked by `robots.txt`

My `robots.txt` is set to disallow /search.
Do you know why:

1. these spam links are doing 3 different things
2. will they impact my site negatively (I've seen some drop in visits since this spam started)
3. Is there anything I can do about it?

Thank you, I've been Googling for days and still confused about a solution.

Comment: I think the best way is to add a robots meta tag / X-Robots-Tag http header, per https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots-meta-tag. This could be done either by changing the code generating the search result to add a <meta name="robots" content="noindex"> tag to the html file, or the server config files (say .htaccess) to add X-Robots-Tag: noindex to URLs starting with "search?q="

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you know if there are any online guides on how to do either of these steps? My robots.txt file is un-editable due to the website builder I use.

Comment: Where does Google say it is finding links to these pages?  I suspect that your site was hacked and that the hacker created links on your own site to them.

Comment: How can any of them be green and indexed if you are disallowing `/search` in robots.txt?  Are some of them using some other URL path?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller "How can any of them be green and indexed if you are disallowing /search in robots.txt?"
This is what has confused me - I don't know how they've indexed - every like has the same structure, something like this - www.example.com/search?q=naza8k-สล๊อค รับเครดิตเล่นฟรี 50

Comment: @StephenOstermiller "Where does Google say it is finding links to these pages?" - They're not in my sitemap nor have any files been uploaded to my site. Google shows this for discovery:
Sitemaps - No referring sitemaps detected
Referring page - is some random jumble of letters for a URL - not my site

Answer (score 0):

If your web server is Apache or LiteSpeed, you can add the X-Robots-Tag by adding the following to .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "^search">
 Header always add X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
</FilesMatch>
```

I don't know what software implements the search functionality for your website, so I can't tell how to change it to add a robots meta tag.